# How to insert HTML into a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have *HTML* Content which was being displayed in a `UITextView`. The next iteration of my app is display the *HTML* contents into a `UIWebView`. So, I basically replaced my `UITextView` with `UIWebView`.  However I could not figure out how to insert my *HTML* snippet into the view.  It seems to need a `URLRequest` which I do not want. I have already stored the *HTML* content in memory and want to load and display it from memory.

Any ideas how I should proceed?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
[myUIWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Also, the HTML can contain links with non-real targets so that the native app can capture the clicks on those using shouldStartLoadRequest delegate and execute custom native code. ex :  - `NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body>  <a href='r:'>Record</a><br><br>   <a href='s:'>Stop</a><br><br> <a href='p:'>Play</a><br><br>   </body><html>";`

Comment: `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *URL = [request URL];
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"r"])
    {
        [self recordButtonMethod];
        return NO;
    }
    
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"s"])
    {
        [self stopButtonMethod];
        return NO;
    }
    
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"p"])
    {
        [self playButtonMethod];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
    
}`//method to capture link-clicks

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;
```

baseURL can be a fileURL to your resources folder if you have any images.

Comment: ...or just `nil` if your HTML doesn't reference external files.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how we can se `HTML` into `UIWebView` and

```
func someFunction() {

    uiWebView.loadHTMLString("<html><body></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
    uiWebView.delegate = self as? UIWebViewDelegate
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    //ready to be processed
}
```

Do not forget to extend a class from `UIWebViewDelegate` and nil the delegate